# @Autowired gives different object in each time of JUnit test

Tags: spring, junit

I have a class named **TestedClass** that is annotated with **@Service("service")**. 
I want to inject this class in my JUnit Test Class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class JUnitTest { 

@Autowired
TestedClass testedClass;

@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(testedClass.toString());
}
```

And then I start my server and run this **JUnitTest** class. 
I think that the output should be same in each time of test without stop the server. But it print different results.

```
TestedClass@1ed4b47
TestedClass@12f9e9
```

Why?

Comment: Your question is not complete. Usually you don't start a server (whatever you mean by "server") to run unit tests. You have to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the test multiple times, different instances of the bean will get injected.  Once you run the test the first bean will get destroyed.  When you run the test again a new instance (singleton) must be made.  The test framework will fire up an IOC container once per run of the test, the beans will not persist across multiple runs.

Comment: Actually I want to test already injected **testedClass** object in **JUnitTest** class. But these two objects are not same.

Comment: @PyaeThuAung But are you running the test multiple times?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't get already injected object **testClass** by this code.